# connection time out while deploying war file with jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I have jenkins configured, which take code form git and converts in war with help of maven. and deploy on the server.

But i am having some trouble in this process. I am able to build war successfully but unable to deploy with tomcat manager and getting connection timed out error.

what could be the possible reason.

here is full log for more information

```html
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Admin-App-QC-QA/workspace/target/admin.war]
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:193)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:852)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:534)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
 ... 16 more
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:852)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:534)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have already checked firewall and username and password.

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Answer (score 0):

I came through this couple of times,

1. The tomcat service was not running in the server, so started it (startup.sh).
2. I was using EC2 instance without elastic IP, whenever I turn on the system it will come up with a new Public IP, so please check the IP address of the server that you have mentioned in Jenkins (http://IPADDRESS:8080/).